# Which is the more natural way to ask the reason for which no one's here?

Tags: sentence-choice

There are 2 sentences asking for a reason:

1. Why is there no one here?
2. Why is no one here?

They both seem grammatically correct, but which is more natural? Is there any nuance between the two?

Comment: Neither is more, or less, natural, and 'Why isn't anyone here?' is possible too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences:

> 1. Why is there no one here?
> 2. Why is no one here?
> 3. Why isn't anyone here?
> 4. Where is everyone?

Are all grammatically valid, and all are quite natural, and might well be said by a fluent speaker. They all carry essentially the same meaning. Sentences 2 and 4 might be used slightly more frequently, because they are shorter. But the difference will not be large, I believe. Any of these is perfectly acceptable.